# Get view child element without @ViewChild decorator in Angular 6

Tags: angular

I have a custom component's decorator:

```
export const MyDecorator = () => {
  return (constructor: Function) => {
    constructor.prototype['ngAfterViewInit'] = function() {
      // I need to get component's view child here
    };      
  };
};
```

I need to get a view child element inside the decorator. In component I could get this element using @ViewChild decorator:

```
@MyDecorator()
@Component({
  selector: "app-my-component",
  templateUrl: "./my-component.html"
})
export class MyPage {
  @ViewChild(Content) content: Content;
}
```

How to get content element in MyDecorator?

Comment: Can you use QueryList?

Comment: I don't understand how to use QueryList in my case

Answer (score 1):

No way to reference DOM of the component before its initialization. If you use class decorator you cannot operate on non-existent document structure. What I would suggest is to move this logic into the component.

Property decorator enable you to pass DOM element as a parameter.

Comment: I need to get DOM of the component after component's initialization. (updated decorator's code in my question)

Comment: I mean it's not possible to do so in decorator taking into account lifecycle of the component. You are not able to operate on DOM (ViewChild retrieves DOM) which has not exist yet. Decorator gets component definition object, but it's not yet created (that's why you can overwrite its prototype). Component structure (template stuff) is calling to life during initialization process. Injector does its work later - based on use case - but generally while module is being created.